# Why can't my servers talk to each other over direct ethernet connection?

Tags: linux, networking, rhel

I have two servers running RHEL 7.2.  Each have 2 NICs.  One NIC talks to a switch, and other is a direct connection between the two servers.  One of the servers will be an NFS server, and the second will do NFS over the private shared network.  I have a physical connection between the two servers (active link lights), but no traffic.  Suggestions?

## SERVER 1

Private network NIC:

```
4: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:f1:df:74:06:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.10/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::aef1:dfff:fe74:6f9/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## SERVER 2

```
3: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:f1:df:74:05:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.11/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::aef1:dfff:fe74:5fc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On server 2....

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0  proto static  metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp5s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.11  metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.125  metric 100
```

When I run tcpdump on both systems' enp5s0, and try to ssh from server 2 to server 1, I see the following on server 2's enp5s0, but nothing on server 1...

```
07:17:45.936772 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.10 (Broadcast) tell h2.atgreen.org, length 28
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you using a [crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable)? Or, do your NICs allow MDI-X (automatic crossover)? Two NICs can't connect directly without either.

Comment: What BinaryZebra said!  Also, what does `ip route` say on Server 1? You may need to put a static route on both of them, for each other's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Gah!  @BinaryZebra is right!  These new NICs don't support MDI-X.  Thanks for pointing this out!

```
# ethtool -s enp5s0 mdix auto
setting MDI not supported
```